# Batch file to append folder names with timestamp and move to destination directory

Tags: batch-file, timestamp, append, move

This seems to me like it would be a commonly asked question, but I've spent hours on Google and haven't been able to find a proper solution.

I have folders in a source directory:
C:\backups

I have set up a destination directory:
C:\archive

I simply need a batch file that will:
1) Add a timestamp to all of the folders (*not the files inside them*) in the source directory, and 
2) then move them to the destination directory.

It would be nice if the .bat file could also write to a log file in case something failed.

Here is the code that I found, but it only copies the files inside the folders and not the folders themselves.  I need both files and folders, with the timestamp added to the folder.

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime /value') do set "dt=%%a"
set "YY=%dt:~2,2%" & set "YYYY=%dt:~0,4%" & set "MM=%dt:~4,2%" & set "DD=%dt:~6,2%"
set "HH=%dt:~8,2%" & set "Min=%dt:~10,2%" & set "Sec=%dt:~12,2%"

SET "DATE_FOLDER=%YYYY%%MM%%DD%"

cd /d "C:\LC_Data_Review\backups\"
SET "ACHIEVE_DIR=C:\archived_data_packages\" 
md "%ACHIEVE_DIR%" 2>nul

for /r %%a in (*) do (
for /r %%b in (*) do move "%%~b" "%ACHIEVE_DIR%\%%~nb - %DATE_FOLDER%%%~xb"
rd /s /q "%%a"
)
```

The above code only copies the files.

Thank you in advance to anyone who can provide the code to do this!

Kevin

Answer (score 1):

You can use this script to help. First, it takes the date and time, then it stores it as a variable and renames it and stuff. Path as in path, and start and finish as the paths for start and finish places.

```
REM Date and time code taken from http://www.winnetmag.com/windowsscripting/article/articleid/9177/windowsscripting_9177.html
@echo off
for /f "tokens=1-7 delims=:/-, " %%i in ('echo exit^|cmd /q /k"prompt $d $t"') do (
   for /f "tokens=2-4 delims=/-,() skip=1" %%a in ('echo.^|date') do (
      set dow=%%i
      set %%a=%%j
      set %%b=%%k
      set %%c=%%l
      set hh=%%m
      set min=%%n
      set ss=%%o
   )
)

echo %dow% %yy%-%mm%-%dd% @ %hh%:%min%:%ss%
pause
      set %%c=%%l
      set hh=%%m
      set min=%%n
      set ss=%%o
   )
)

set filename=%dow% %yy%-%mm%-%dd% @ %hh%:%min%:%ss%
for /D %%f in (C:path) do rename "%%f" "%%~nxf_%filename%"
robocopy c:\start c:\finish /e
```

Comment: Thank you Kumquat for the helpful info.  I'll run this in the morning and let you know how it worked!

Comment: Thank you again!  I wasn't sure what to replace "C:path" with, so I used the path to the source directory.  The .bat file copied only the subfolders, but none of the files within them, and didn't append anything with a timestamp.  I need to have the folders and their files copied.

Comment: Also, the original folder still remained in the source directory instead of being moved to the destination.

Comment: @Systech, whoops so sorry about that. Seems like you found an answer already, so great job!

Comment: No worries - thanks again for your help. I appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution for you:

Assuming you a create batch file named archive.bat with the following contents:

```
for /d %%d in (%1\*) do (xcopy "%%d\*" "%2\%%~nxd-%DATE:~-4%-%DATE:~4,2%-%DATE:~7,2%" /E /V /I)&&(rd "%%d" /s /q)
```

The you call it:

```
archive.bat C:\backups C:\archive
```

Given folders:

```
C:\backups\one
C:\backups\two
```

You will get:

```
C:\archive\one-YYYY-MM-DD
C:\archive\two-YYYY-MM-DD
```

Where YYYY-MM-DD is the current date.  Change the date format string as needed.

The steps taken are:

1. Use for /d to iterate subdirectories of the path specified in the first argument (%1).
2. Use xcopy to move all contents of each directory to subdirectory of path specified in second argument (%2) with timestamp appended.  xcopy /I specifes to create new timestamped directory.
3. Remove source directory recursively without prompt.

Here is the output from my test:

```
C:\>dir C:\backups /b /s
C:\backups\One
C:\backups\Two
C:\backups\One\alpha
C:\backups\One\beta
C:\backups\One\alpha\New Bitmap Image.bmp
C:\backups\One\alpha\New Rich Text Document.rtf
C:\backups\One\alpha\New Text Document.txt
C:\backups\One\beta\New Bitmap Image.bmp
C:\backups\One\beta\New Rich Text Document.rtf
C:\backups\One\beta\New Text Document.txt
C:\backups\Two\alpha
C:\backups\Two\beta
C:\backups\Two\alpha\New Bitmap Image.bmp
C:\backups\Two\alpha\New Rich Text Document.rtf
C:\backups\Two\alpha\New Text Document.txt
C:\backups\Two\beta\New Bitmap Image.bmp
C:\backups\Two\beta\New Rich Text Document.rtf
C:\backups\Two\beta\New Text Document.txt

C:\>test C:\backups C:\archive\
C:\backups\One\alpha\New Bitmap Image.bmp
C:\backups\One\alpha\New Rich Text Document.rtf
C:\backups\One\alpha\New Text Document.txt
C:\backups\One\beta\New Bitmap Image.bmp
C:\backups\One\beta\New Rich Text Document.rtf
C:\backups\One\beta\New Text Document.txt
6 File(s) copied

C:\backups\Two\alpha\New Bitmap Image.bmp
C:\backups\Two\alpha\New Rich Text Document.rtf
C:\backups\Two\alpha\New Text Document.txt
C:\backups\Two\beta\New Bitmap Image.bmp
C:\backups\Two\beta\New Rich Text Document.rtf
C:\backups\Two\beta\New Text Document.txt
6 File(s) copied

C:\>dir C:\archive /b /s
C:\archive\One-2017-08-09
C:\archive\Two-2017-08-09
C:\archive\One-2017-08-09\alpha
C:\archive\One-2017-08-09\beta
C:\archive\One-2017-08-09\alpha\New Bitmap Image.bmp
C:\archive\One-2017-08-09\alpha\New Rich Text Document.rtf
C:\archive\One-2017-08-09\alpha\New Text Document.txt
C:\archive\One-2017-08-09\beta\New Bitmap Image.bmp
C:\archive\One-2017-08-09\beta\New Rich Text Document.rtf
C:\archive\One-2017-08-09\beta\New Text Document.txt
C:\archive\Two-2017-08-09\alpha
C:\archive\Two-2017-08-09\beta
C:\archive\Two-2017-08-09\alpha\New Bitmap Image.bmp
C:\archive\Two-2017-08-09\alpha\New Rich Text Document.rtf
C:\archive\Two-2017-08-09\alpha\New Text Document.txt
C:\archive\Two-2017-08-09\beta\New Bitmap Image.bmp
C:\archive\Two-2017-08-09\beta\New Rich Text Document.rtf
C:\archive\Two-2017-08-09\beta\New Text Document.txt
```

Comment: Thank you Karl for the helpful info.  I'll report back in the morning.  Much appreciated!

Comment: This worked great!  Thank you!  How do I get the script to copy the files inside the subdirectories?

Comment: This script is already written to recursively copy the files with the xcopy /E argument which even copies empty directories (feel free to change it if needed.)

Comment: I've added the output of my test showing the recursive file copy.  If you like this one-line solution, don't forget to upvote.

Comment: I must have been doing something wrong.  It works perfectly now! Many thanks!